# Safari iFrame cookie issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, safari

I realize that there are several questions related to this; however I've been going crazy trying to make this work.  Simply put, I have an MVC3 application that lives on our company's server, and it is served up in an iFrame on a client's URL.  All is fine and dandy with every other browser, execpt for Safari, which has the whole "no third party cookies" setting turned on by default.

So here's what I've tried so far (we have custom libraries, so some of these functions are specific to our stuff):

View:

```
@if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().IndexOf("safari") >= 0) && HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["safari_cookie_set"] == null)
{
  using (Html.BeginRouteFormSSL(RouteNames.SafariRedirect, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "safari-fix-form" }))
  {   <input type="submit" value="Go!" /> }
}
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public virtual ActionResult SafariRedirect()
{
  ActionResult result = null;

  Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("safari_cookie_set", "cookie ok"));
  result = RedirectToRouteNoSSL(Index);

  return result;
}
```

Javascript:

```
safariValidate: function(){
  if ($.browser.safari == true && document.cookie.indexOf("safari_cookie_set") == -1){
          $("#safari-fix-form").submit();
      }
}
```

So initially, the premise was to automatically post to the iframe using javascript (thus the .submit()).  It seemed to work, for a day or so.  Now, it doesn't matter how I post (notice the input button here...), a cookie will NOT be set within an iframe.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much deliberation and fighting with different browsers, our company finally decided to ditch cookies in favor of using database based sessions.  This completely resolves the issue since we are dealing with a third party website hosting our site in an iframe.

Hopefully this will help others - there is no clean way to use cookies in an iframe.

Comment: How do you persist the session across pages requests inside of your iframe?

Comment: This was created / done over two years ago, but if I remember correctly, we would pass a session GUID around and always include it in the model bases.  That way, the GUID would be available no matter where you came from, but this is also going from very leaky memory.